# AngularJS - How to data bind an object within a JSON object

Tags: json, angularjs

Using the included http post, I should get back the JSON object below. I want to take the LeagueDictionary data in the JSON below and create an object so I can use it in a for each loop on my client, but I can't wrap my head around how to structure that code in the http call.

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "UserName": null,
    "NickName": null,
    "Email": "email@company.com",
    "Password": null,
    "Admin": false,
    "Validated": false,
    "Key": "oOE0QbOhjK17pNeKDPEFti5On27R3b",
    "LeagueDictionary": {
        "1": "League #1",
        "2": "League #2"
    }
}
```

using this call:

```
$scope.getLeagues = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            data: ???,
        })
    }
```

If someone give me a nudge on how to data bind that particular part of the JSON, I'd appreciate the help. I'm not sure how to strip the LeagueDictionary section out and make an object out of it.

Comment: SO you need to extract what is in LeagueDictionary and pass it into your request?

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Are you expecting that JSON data back as a response from the POST?  Or are you trying to send it in the POST body?

Comment: Sorry, yes, if I use the http call provided, that JSON object should be returned. I want to use the LeagueDictionary part to create an object that I can use in an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a service that gets your data, so you can get `$http` and such out of your controller. Say...

```
app.factory('DataService', function ($http) {
  return {
    get: function () {
      return $http.get('data.json'); // post & url goes here
    }
  };
});
```

In your controller, use `then` to access the response data after `promise` has been resolved (catch() and finally() are available, too).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, DataService) {
  DataService.get().then(function (response) {
    $scope.leagueDictionary = response.data.LeagueDictionary;
  });
});
```

Related HTML template would be

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-show="leagueDictionary">
    <span ng-repeat="(key,val) in leagueDictionary">
      {{ val }} <br>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Using your data this gives you

[image: imgur]

---

See example plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/j6bmmQ

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the `LeagueDictionary` property of the response, and then iterate over that in `ng-repeat`.  Obviously I don't know exactly what your scopes look like, but this should get you started:

```
//JS
$http.post('/someUrl', { 'foo': 'bar' }).success(function(data) {
    myController.myModel.leagueDictionary = data.LeagueDictionary;
});

//HTML
<tr ng-repeat="(leagueNum, leagueName) in leagueDictionary">
```